# How to keep URL's parameters with Html.PagedListPager

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new Html.PagedListPager and trying to use it in my project. It seems very usefull but I have a problem to solve.

when I use code below, everything works as expected. But when I click one of the page number with the below code, It clears all URL parameters.

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, Page=> Url.Action("Products", new { Page,  sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }), PagedListRenderOptions.ClassicPlusFirstAndLast)
```

When I click one of the pages, I lose Category and Brand values from the URL

```
http://localhost:53307/Home/Products?Page=2&Category=Steel&Brand=BMW
```

this url gets changed to

```
http://localhost:53307/Home/Products?Page=2
```

How can I keep the Brand and Category values? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is nothing in your code relating to `Category` and `Brand` - the only parameters you have added are for `sortOrder` and `currentFilter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Products",
                            new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort,  Category = ViewBag.Category, Brand = ViewBag.Brand }))
```

And in controller action :

```
 public ActionResult Products(string SortOrder, string Category,sting Brand, int? Page)
{
            ViewBag.CurrentSort = SortOrder;
            ViewBag.Category= Category;
            ViewBag.Brand= Brand;
 }
```